# Can the phrase 'is contained in' be substituted by a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, transitive-verbs

If a lunchbox contains an apple, then the apple *is contained in* a lunchbox. Is it possible to replace the phrase 'is contained in' with a single word? I can't think of one, and the thesaurus hasn't been very helpful, either.

Comment: You could just say "is in"?

Comment: @Kian:  Excellent.  Plus one for brevity, succinctness, simplicity.  On the other side of the spectrum (i.e., prolixity) you could have:  "The content of the lunchbox is comprised of a single apple," but then this version does not simplify things, does it?!

Comment: "is in" is the most natural sounding and immediate expression. Kian should write his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **occupy**, meaning to fill or take up (a space or time).

"The apple occupies the lunchbox."
"The sofa occupies the entire room."

There don't appear to be too many single words meeting your requirement. If you were referring to an animal rather than an apple, you could use *inhabit*.

Comment: I was writing an answer with those very words when you posted yours. =)

Comment: Occupies I think is different I think it implies that the apple takes over all the box

Answer (score 2):

*Is in*, *is within*, or *is inside* typically can substitute for *is contained in*.  Eg,  “The apple is inside the lunchbox.”  Making *lunchbox* the subject of course gives you a short sentence that includes *contain*:  “The lunch box contains an apple.”

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is **inhabit**. According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inhabit?s=t), it is used of things that are capable of locomotion or of abstract things, so it will seem a little ridiculous in this context. **Occupy** is another word, but the best thing to do by far is just to say "is contained in" or "is in", as Kian has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The apple **held** in the lunch box.

Comment: There are two ways to read this sentence. Either you this means the apple is constraining the lunch box in some way (like "*the police held in the crowd*"), which is not at all what OP meant, or you mean is, "*the apple is held in the lunch box*," which doesn't replace the phrase "*is contained in*"--it only replaces the word *contained*. Either way I don't think this really answers the question.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I don't believe the other answers do either, with the exceptions of "is in" and "inside". Nevertheless, the meaning of *hold* is quite similar to *contain* and sounds quite elegant to my ear.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, After all, "is contained in a" has four words, my solution: "held in the" has *only* three words.

Answer (score -4):

The lunch box **includes** an apple.

Comment: Answering the wrong question: OP asked 'the apple ???s the lunchbox'.

Comment: Answer works, just involves moving a few other words in the sentence around. Original question does not forbid that.

Comment: If you're rearranging other words, you've missed the point of the question. And even if OP had explicitly allowed swapping the subject and object, the best answer would simply be **contains**.